# RestEasy 406 not acceptable

Tags: java, rest, api, resteasy, http-status-code-406

I am testing a REST service I created, that constantly gives me the error: No match for accept header

```
    @POST
    @Path("token/{tid}/used")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Produces("image/png")
    public Response useTokens(@PathParam("tid") String tokenId, String input) {
        try {
            String test = input + "test";
            if (tokenService.useToken(tokenId)) {
                return Response.accepted().entity(tokenService.getTokenImage(tokenId)).build();
            } else if (!tokenService.useToken(tokenId)) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.FORBIDDEN).entity("Token already used or wrong token id").build();
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Token not found").build();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

and my test looks like

```
    String tokenId = "12345234";
    RestClient useTokenClient = new RestClient("http://localhost:8080/token/");
    String url = String.format("%s/used", tokenId);
    String trigger = "trigger resteasy";
    tokenResponse = this.useTokenClient.post(url, trigger, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

I don't actually need the String trigger in the test class or the String input in my API, but RestEasy apparently cannot send post requests without a body.

Comment: I suspect that you are using wrong REST endpoint URI. Seems to be a missing identifier before `token`

Comment: I dont think that is the issue. When I post it using Postman, with the same URI, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a [content negotiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation) problem. The definition of HTTP 406 taken from the [mozilla project](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) is:

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 406 Not Acceptable client error
>   response code indicates that the server cannot produce a response
>   matching the list of acceptable values defined in the request's
>   proactive content negotiation headers, and that the server is
>   unwilling to supply a default representation.

Indeed, your endpoint defines that it is producing *"image/png"*, but your client is accepting *MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN*.

So you need to align these two, if the token is an image change the client, if it is pain text change the server code.